# Multiple pip in \Scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-import

newbie here. I am using pycharm with python 3.8, for some reason I can't import any module. When I tried to install from the command line, it said:
"'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Same result with pip3. Furthermore, when looking in the \Scripts directory I have
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBZqn.png)

So it seems pip is there, but is it problem I have multiple?

Comment: You may not have written the directory to the environment variable.

Comment: If you run `python --version` in the command line, does it work? You probably need to set python as an environment variable. You can add it to *PATH* with the python installer. Here's an [article](https://medium.com/@omoshalewa/why-you-should-add-python-to-path-and-how-58693c17c443) about it.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well: it gives 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: If you can use `python` command, you should also be able to use `python -m pip install` to install packages. Assuming that python command will run.

Comment: @paloman for "python -m  pip install" it gives "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: @ElettraCorso I would follow this [article](https://medium.com/@omoshalewa/why-you-should-add-python-to-path-and-how-58693c17c443). The problem is that python is not added to *PATH* environment variable.

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum I have also added it to the path, thanks for the suggestion. However it still doesn't recognize python or pip as commands from the command line

Comment: @ElettraCorso Make sure you restart your command line or restart pycharm.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I think I needed to add to PATH, as  @JeffGruenbaum pointed out!Thanks so much!